# How to search a JSON with utf-8 characters in jQuery like SQL LIKE %value% statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, utf-8

I have JSON data with UTF-8 characters and I want to search it something like the SQL `LIKE %value%` statement.

Below is the code - it works fine when you write name in English:

```js
  jsonData ='[{"id":19,"cost":400,"name":"Ø§Ø³Ù„Ù…","height":198,"weight":35},{"id":21,"cost":250,"name":"ÙØ±Ø­Ø§Ù†","height":216,"weight":54},{"id":38,"cost":450,"name":"Ø¹Ù„ÛŒ","height":147,"weight":22}]';
  array = JSON.parse(jsonData);
  var result = array.filter((x) => x.name.toLowerCase().indexOf("ا") >= 0);
  console.log(result);
```

Here is the same code with english data its works fine

```js
 jsonData ='[{"id":19,"cost":400,"name":"arian","height":198,"weight":35},{"id":21,"cost":250,"name":"Arkanss","height":216,"weight":54},{"id":38,"cost":450,"name":"Jumla","height":147,"weight":22}]';
  array = JSON.parse(jsonData);
  var result = array.filter((x) => x.name.toLowerCase().indexOf("r") >= 0);
  console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved it by simply punting a meta tag in the page

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" />
```